# why each openstack nova services has 3 rabbitmq consumers associated with it

Tags: rabbitmq, openstack

In openstack nova, different types of rabbitmq consumers ((ex. topic consumer, node_topic consumer, fanout consumer) are associated with each nova services (ex. nova-schedule, nova-compute etc) .  Following lines is an  Excerpt from https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/master/nova/service.py which uses 3 consumers for each nova service.FYI: service.py is a wrapper for generating nova-services.

```
self.conn.create_consumer(self.topic, rpc_dispatcher, fanout=False)

node_topic = '%s.%s' % (self.topic, self.host)
self.conn.create_consumer(node_topic, rpc_dispatcher, fanout=False)

self.conn.create_consumer(self.topic, rpc_dispatcher, fanout=True)
```

I guess, each consumer is associated with a different Rabbit Queue. I think, we may need a node_topic consumer for sending messages directly to a node. what may be  the purposes of two other consumers ( topic, & fanout consumer ) in each service?

Also, when I list exchanges of rabbitmq in my devstack node with the following command, it shows a whole lot of (11685) messages

```
stack@9734efd5-6fcd-4127-92b4-6715a66fda9d:/opt/stack$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_exchanges | wc -l
11685
```

can someone explain why are there so many exchanges in the rabbitmq of openstack devstack implemenation?